# Create combinations from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

Table 1

```
name, weight
A, 4
B, 2
C, 1
```

Table 2

```
name, weight
AA, 4
BB, 2
CC, 1
```

Table 3

```
name, weight
AAA, 4
BBB, 2
CCC, 1
```

I want to create all combinations of tables and then order it by total weight (sum of weights). Example

```
A, AA, AAA, 12
A, BB, AAA, 10
A, CC, AAA, 9
A, AA, BBB, 10
A, BB, BBB, 8
A, CC, BBB, 7
A, AA, CCC, 9
A, BB, CCC, 7
A, CC, CCC, 6
...
C, CC, CCC, 3
```

Is it possible with SQL ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible with cross join

```
select 
  t1.name as name1, 
  t2.name as name2, 
  t3.name as name3, 
  t1.weight + t2.weight + t3.weight as weight
from table1 t1,
  table2 t2,
  table3 t3
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
select  
  t1.name as name1, 
  t2.name as name2, 
  t3.name as name3,
  t1.weight + t2.weight + t3.weight as weight
from table1 t1
cross join table2 t2
cross join table3 t3
```

If your `weight` column might hold `null` values you will need `coalesce` function to avoid getting `null` as the output and treat those values as `0`s :

```
select 
  t1.name as name1, 
  t2.name as name2, 
  t3.name as name3, 
  coalesce(t1.weight,0) + coalesce(t2.weight,0) + coalesce(t3.weight,0) as weight
from table1 t1
cross join table2 t2
cross join table3 t3
```

Comment: @Strawberry 1 coalesce won't do it here. `weight` in any table can be null. Or am I missing something?